# List size goes back to zero for some reason

Tags: java, android, list

I am loading data from cloud `firestore` into a custom recyclerview adapter. According to my log I get the data from `firestore` just fine and inside of my get method the log shows my list size increasing. Outside of my get method **mWorkoutList** goes back to size 0. I cannot figure out why this is happening.[image: Log shows mWorkoutList size going back to 0]

```
public class ViewWorkoutsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkoutAdapter.WorkoutAdapterOnClickHandler {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private String mUid;
private List<Set> mSetList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private WorkoutAdapter mWorkoutAdapter;
private List<OtherWorkout> mWorkoutList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_workouts);
    mWorkoutList = new ArrayList<>();
    mUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    initDatabaseData();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mWorkoutAdapter = new WorkoutAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWorkoutAdapter);
    Log.i("LOG", "workout list size HERE: " + mWorkoutList.size());
    mWorkoutAdapter.setWorkoutData(mWorkoutList);
}

@Override
public void onClick(OtherWorkout workout) {

}

public void initDatabaseData(){
    CollectionReference collectionReference2 = db.collection("users").document(mUid).collection("workouts");
    collectionReference2.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                            OtherWorkout workout = document.toObject(OtherWorkout.class);
                            mWorkoutList.add(workout);
                            Log.i("LOG", "workout list size: " + mWorkoutList.size());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: can you please show us where you have printed the log of outside get method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Allen you are calling initDatabaseData(); in oncreate() method which is making Network Request and fetching data. So it takes roughly around 2-3 seconds to fetch the data. But In that 2-3 seconds your code below initDatabaseData() getting called

```
 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager
        = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mWorkoutAdapter = new WorkoutAdapter(this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWorkoutAdapter);
Log.i("LOG", "workout list size HERE: " + mWorkoutList.size());
mWorkoutAdapter.setWorkoutData(mWorkoutList);
```

So till the data has not come the listsize will display 0 and then after you get the data in onComplete() list size will increase(). So basically add a line mWorkoutAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); here:-

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                        OtherWorkout workout = document.toObject(OtherWorkout.class);
                        mWorkoutList.add(workout);
                        Log.i("LOG", "workout list size: " + mWorkoutList.size());
                    }mWorkoutAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

                }
```

This will refresh your Adapter with your new values.

Comment: That did the trick. Now my adapter is loading the workouts. Thank you for the clear explanation. I didn't even consider the few second delay for the network request.

Answer (score 0):

You create `OtherWorkout` as a local object, then add it to the collection. 
If your `get()` function runs out of scope the object will be automatically deleted.

I didn't check but I think the Java garbage collection will take care of the rest and delete the object from the Array.

You should create the objects on the Heap with `new` so they will persist outside of the scope of that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your

```
  Log.i("LOG", "workout list size: " + mWorkoutList.size());
```

after

```
 Log.i("LOG", "workout list size HERE: " + mWorkoutList.size());
```

so it means firebase take some some time for fetch  all data , in period of this time your rest of code are executed.
so the solution is called initDatabaseData() after set the adapter then adapter.notifydatasetchanged() called. or you can direct notify the adapter in initDatabaseData() method after fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

`addOnCompleteListener` provides a way to add **asynchronous** task listener.

When you call `initDatabaseData()`, you start the task and define a listener. But there is no guarantee that this task is completed when returning from `initDatabaseData`.

That's why, once you print `mWorkoutList` size in the `onCreate` method, the value can be different from the one printed in the listener.

To avoid that, you can change the way your program works either by changing the async mechanism to a sync one, or by the part using the data to the listener `onComplete` method